# Import millis() in processing library

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to write a library called "Visione" in Processing using the [processing-library-template](https://github.com/processing/processing-library-template#AddingJARs) here.

Unfortunately Eclipse gives me the following error:

```
[javac]   long    lastIpCameraRead = millis();
[javac]                                ^
[javac]   symbol:   method millis()
[javac]   location: class Visione
```

I noticed the errors also occurs in most of the basics Processing functions like delay(), stroke(), etc.

This is the list of the imports:

```
import processing.core.*;
import gab.opencv.*;
import ipcapture.*;
import g4p_controls.*    ;
import processing.video.*;
import java.awt.*        ;
import java.util.*;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in a class other than your main sketch, you can't access Processing's functions directly.

Instead, you'd probably want to pass a `PApplet` reference into your class, and use that to call Processing's functions. Something like this:

```
public class MyClass{
   public MyClass(PApplet sketch){
      long time = sketch.millis();
   }
}
```

Then in your sketch code, you would use the `this` keyword to pass in a self-reference to the sketch:

```
void setup(){
   size(500, 500);
   new MyClass(this);
}
```